# Angular v15 Application Broken After Migrating redux-devtools-extension package moved to @redux-devtools/extension

Tags: angular, redux, angular15, redux-devtools-extension

Issue Overview:
After redux-devtools-extension package moved to @redux-devtools/extension package, I am encountering TypeScript errors in my project. These errors seem to be related to type definitions in the package.

More details click on [link](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/1532)

Comment: Have you installed @types/react-redux ?

Comment: not have install,i will installing now

Comment: @types/react-redux Installed but not working still same error